# Chat is getting delayed in Quickblox

Tags: quickblox

When posting a message in group chat its getting delayed by 5-6seconds. Though in one to one chat is real time chat and instant. So is it possible to optimise the time it will take for acknowledgment.

Comment: which platform do you use? please add proper tag (ios/android/..). Also can you post some snippet you use to send group messages

Comment: @Igor I am using web platform. In the same platform when I send message privately, it immediately sends the same. But group chat takes 2-3 seconds to actually show up message in chat view in website. The scripts and codes are same which Quickblox provides. Isn't it happening of the shared server they provide?